# Integer - ArrayList -

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am facing problem in retrieving and putting integers in an `ArrayList`. Logcat shows nothing

```
public void GetRecipes(String meal_cat_selected, ArrayList<String> User_Main_Ing) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        User_Main_Ingredients = User_Main_Ing;
        for (int i = 0; i <User_Main_Ingredients.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("User_Main_Ingredients", User_Main_Ingredients.get(i).toString());
        }

        String mealcat=meal_cat_selected;
        Cursor cursor_recipes = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + RECIPE_COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + RECIPES_TABLE_NAME + " where " + MEAL_CATEGORY + "=" + mealcat, null);
       int i,id;
        cursor_recipes.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor_recipes.isAfterLast() == false) {
            recipes.add(cursor_recipes.getInt(cursor_recipes.getColumnIndex(RECIPE_COLUMN_ID)));
            cursor_recipes.moveToNext();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("Recipes",Integer.toString(recipes.get(i)));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++) {
            id = recipes.get(i);
            boolean result = checkrecipe(id);
            if (result == true) {
                matchedRecipes[i] = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: reverse the edit this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your arraylist is not an integer arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> User_Main_Ingredients;
```

change that to

```
ArrayList<Integer> User_Main_Ingredients;
```

and you can get integers by using a for loop

```
 for(int ingredient : User_Main_Ingredients){
  System.out.println(ingredient);
 }
```

in your receipes list its already a integer arraylist so no need of converting

```
for (int rec :recipes) {
    System.out.println("Recipes"+rec);
    }
```

Comment: Its not user_Main_Ingredients. Its  the recipe (Integer Array List) It is declared up.  How do I use that for loop?

Comment: Cursor cursor_recipes = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + RECIPE_COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + RECIPES_TABLE_NAME + " where " + MEAL_CATEGORY + "=" + mealcat, null);
       int i,id;
        cursor_recipes.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor_recipes.isAfterLast() == false) {
            recipes.add(cursor_recipes.getInt(cursor_recipes.getColumnIndex(RECIPE_COLUMN_ID)));
            cursor_recipes.moveToNext();
        }